# Positioning submenu inside main menu item on mobile and under the main menu on desktop

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design

This is a general question. I imagine the following menu for desktop
[image]

and the following for mobile

[image]

i have tried different approaches:

1: Use two different headers and show hide them with css, easy to style but not ideal regarding screenreader.

```
<header class="mobile-header">
</header>
<header class="desktop-header">
</header>
```

2: Use one header:

```
<header>
<h1 aria-label="Brandname">
  <a class="" href="/">
    Brandname
  </a>
</h1>

<nav class="main-menu-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <button class="toggle-mobile-menu" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="/">Menu Item 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Submenu Item 1</li>
                    <li>Submenu Item 2 </li>
                </ul>       
            </li>
            <li><a href="/">Menu Item 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Submenu Item 1</li>
                    <li>Submenu Item 2 </li>                    
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/">Menu Item 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>Submenu Item 1</li>
                    <li>Submenu Item 2 </li>                    
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </ul>
</nav>

</header>
```

Regarding the syntax I like this structure. And on mobile it is working great but how can I style it for desktop? I thought of using `position: absolute` on the submenu but I am not so sure about this approach because than I need to calculate the height using javascript.
Maybe there is a simple solution?

Example:

Like on this website: https://www.bruecke-museum.de/

Desktop:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

But it seems like they use two different header elements, which I would like to avoid

Comment: try to use @media query for mobile design [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp], for position absolute, it will not be a good idea for responsive design, try to use flex or grid, it will make it more responsive.

Comment: How can I position the submenu for desktop like in my sketch with the structure above by using flexbox?

Comment: You want it in the same line and without showing other menu elements, just one menu element, Am I correct?

Comment: maybe I found an answer here: https://bbc.github.io/gel/components/site-menu/ https://bbc.github.io/gel/components/demos/site-menu/#

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-menu{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
  ul{
      display: flex;
      gap:50px

    }
```

```html
<header>
<h1 aria-label="Brandname">
  <a class="" href="/">
    Brandname
  </a>
</h1>

<nav class="main-menu-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <button class="toggle-mobile-menu" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="/">Menu Item 1</a>
                <ul id="addclasshere">
                    <li>Submenu Item 1</li>
                    <li>Submenu Item 2 </li>
                </ul>       
            </li>
            <li><a href="/">Menu Item 1</a>
                <ul id="addclasshere">
                    <li>Submenu Item 1</li>
                    <li>Submenu Item 2 </li>                    
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/">Menu Item 3</a>
                <ul id="addclasshere">
                    <li>Submenu Item 1</li>
                    <li>Submenu Item 2 </li>                    
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </ul>
</nav>

</header>
<body></body>
```

If you want to make your menu dropdown and just showing only one of menu items, you have to add js file with `document.getelementById().addclass()` and create another css class with `visibilty="visible`. or you can check for [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)